# Html.ListBox() and MultiselectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've a little problem with an Html.ListBox.

I am developing a personal blog in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and I created an `adminpanel` where I can add and edit a post!
During this two operations, I can add also tags.

I think of use an `Html.ListBox()` helper to list all tags, and so I can select multiple tags to add in a post! The problem isn't during the add mode, but in the edit mode, where I have to pre-select post's tags.

I read that I have to use a `MultiSelectList` and so in its constructor pass, tags' list and tag's list(pre-selected value).

But I don't know how to use this class.

I post, some code:

This is my models method that get all list tags in selectlist

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTagsListBox()
    {
            return   from t in db.Tags
                     orderby t.IDTag descending
                     select new SelectListItem {
                         Text = t.TagName,
                         Value = t.IDTag.ToString(),
                     };
    }
```

So in Edit (Get and Post), Add(Get and Post) I use a ViewData to pass this list in `Html.ListBox()`.

```
ViewData["Tags"] = tagdb.GetTagsListBox();
```

And in my view

```
<%=Html.ListBox("Tags",ViewData["Tags"] as SelectList) %>
```

So with this code it's ok in Add Mode.

But in Edit Mode I need to pre-select those values.

So Now, of course I have to create a method that get all tagsbypostid.

and then in `ViewData` what Must I to pass?

Any suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following I think:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTagsListBoxWithPostTagsSelected(int postID)
{
    // Assuming you need to create this function and that Tag.IDTag is an int
    var postTags = GetAllTagsByPostID(postID);

    return from t in db.Tags           
           orderby t.IDTag descending           
           select new SelectListItem {           
               Text = t.TagName,           
               Value = t.IDTag.ToString(),
               Selected = postTags.Exists(pt => pt.IDTag == t.IDTag)
           };           
}
```

This should return you the proper list with the values from the post selected.

You will need to make the `GetAllTagsByPostID(postID)` and have a new method that takes in a `PostID` to make sure the tags get selected properly.

No change would be required to:

```
<%=Html.ListBox("Tags", ViewData["Tags"] as SelectList) %>
```

The `ViewData["Tags"]` should now contain the required information to select your `ListBox` items.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Selected` property of the `SelectListItem`s for the selected tags to `true`.

Comment: Yes, but in this way it selected all tags,and I need to pre-select all tags that are in post. For example if tags are c#,mvc in my listbox I want to see only this tag preselected and then other all tags not selected. Sorry for exclamation marks.

Comment: You need to set the `Selected` property for that post's tags using a loop.

Comment: So, I can use into select new SelectListItem a loop to iterate a list of tags by PostID, and foreach item it's property to true?

Comment: You should `foreach` the tags in the actual post, then write `tagItems.Single(t => t.Value == tag.IDTag.ToString()).Selected = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found for getting selections to occur in a multi select list using ListBoxFor was posted by another user in this thread; [Challenges with selecting values in ListBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194143/challenges-with-selecting-values-in-listboxfor)

Hope this helps.