# Challenges with selecting values in ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Working on my first ASP.Net MVC2 web app recently, I came across some issues when I needed to select multiple values in a list box.  I worked around it with some jQuery, but went ahead and put together some very simple code to demonstrate. I'm using EF for the model, with two entities - Customers and HelpDeskCalls:

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Customer currCustomer = ctx.Customers.Include("HelpDeskCalls").Where(c => c.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        List<HelpDeskCall> currCustCalls = (ctx.HelpDeskCalls.Where(h => h.CustomerID == id)).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> currSelectItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<String> selectedValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (HelpDeskCall currCall in currCustCalls)
        {
            bool isSelected = (currCall.ID % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
            //Just select the IDs which are even numbers...
            currSelectItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Selected = isSelected, Text = currCall.CallTitle, Value = currCall.ID.ToString() });
            //add the selected values into a separate list as well...
            if (isSelected)
            {
                selectedValues.Add(currCall.ID.ToString());
            }
        }
        ViewData["currCalls"] = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) currSelectItems;
        ViewData["currSelected"] = (IEnumerable<String>) selectedValues;
        return View("Edit", currCustomer);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.HelpDeskCalls, new MultiSelectList(Model.HelpDeskCalls, "ID", "CallTitle", (IEnumerable) ViewData["currSelected"]), new { size = "12" })%>       
    <%: Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.HelpDeskCalls, ViewData["currCalls"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { size = "12"}) %>
    <%: Html.ListBox("Model.HelpDeskCalls", new MultiSelectList(Model.HelpDeskCalls, "ID", "CallTitle", (IEnumerable)ViewData["currSelected"]), new { size = "12"}) %>      
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HelpDeskCalls) %>
</div>
```

For this sample, I'm just selecting HelpDeskCall.IDs which are even.  I'm trying two different syntaxes for ListBoxFor: One uses an IEnumerable of values for selections, one using an IEnumerable of SelectListItems.  By default, when I run this code, no selections are made to either ListBoxFor, but the non-strongly typed ListBox selects correctly.

I read [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1570736.aspx) on ASP.Net and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308846/why-is-listboxfor-not-selecting-items-but-listbox-is) on SO, but no joy.  In fact, if I add the override ToString() to my HelpDeskCall class (as suggested in the ASP.net thread) all values are selected, which isn't right either.

If someone could shed some light on how this should work (and what I'm missing or doing wrong), this then neophyte would be very grateful.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Here's an example illustrating the strongly typed version:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int[] SelectedItemIds { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Preselect items with id 1 and 3
        var selectedItemIds = new[] { 1, 3 };

        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Items = new MultiSelectList(
                new[] 
                {
                    // TODO: Fetch from your repository
                    new { Id = 1, Name = "item 1" },
                    new { Id = 2, Name = "item 2" },
                    new { Id = 3, Name = "item 3" },
                }, 
                "Id", 
                "Name", 
                selectedItemIds
            )
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%: Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedItemIds, Model.Items) %>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I spent a while trying to get this to work. This worked for me also. Many thanks! Upvoting.

Comment: ty! this helped me out a bunch.

Comment: You are the man! :D Thank you for helping with such good and clean samples of code throughout StackOverflow. God bless your life!

Comment: @Darin: If I'd use `MyViewModel` as parameter of a post action will `SelectedItemIds` get populated by the model binder with all the Ids of the items which have been selected in the ListBox on the page?

Comment: @Slauma, yes, that's what will happen.

Comment: @Darin: Thanks. I was asking because of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7259795/270591) and felt my answer in that question is halfbaked (more focussed on the EF part but not the MVC model binding). I'm still not satisfied with my answer but with your solution here at least I see a way how it can work.

Comment: @Darin what is the post action with view model and repository pattern? It would be nice if you include that

Comment: Pay attention that if you need to select multiple values make sure you instantiate the MultiSelectList property with MultiSelectList and not SelectList, took me a lot of effort to understand why I always got only one item selected.

Comment: That's why I don't like Razor

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this behaviour has changed in the RTM of MVC3 that I'm using, but it seems that selection and binding now works out of the box. The only catch is that the model should contain a property with the IDs, like that :

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public int[] ItemIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following in the view would work fine, both pre-selecting the correct values and binding correctly during post:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ItemIDs, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(new[] { 
                                new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1" }, 
                                new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2" } 
                             }))
```

Comment: A small correction. Even though the above works, there seems to be some minor bug that could cause problems. It seems that when the ViewBag contains a property named "X" and the property of the model is also named "X" the automatic selection for the ListBox does not work... Strange things...

Comment: That comment really saved me!

Comment: Still in 2016 this comments is helping me - I had a ViewBag property with the same name as the bound model Property, so the selected items population didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

I have found better workaround. Usual way to preselect select list:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    model => model.Roles, 
    new MultiSelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name")
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles)
```

Doesn't work.., never ever any option is selected, until:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(id);
    // this is workaround for http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/4932?ProjectName=aspnet
    ViewData["Roles"] = user.Roles.Select(r => r.Id);
    return View(user);
}
```

Selected Roles has to be stored in ViewData, to workaround nasty bug.

Comment: Probably obvious (but still nice to know): this also works if you use the MVC3-style ViewBag.Roles.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take advantage of nameof, you could do something like this;

```
Html.ListBox(nameof(MainProjectViewModel.Projects), Model.Projects)
```