# MVC: Selected values in a listbox when the user is on the edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, selectedvalue

Im using MVC3 EF-model first on my project.

When a user create a question, he/she can choose multiple CoreValues from a ListBox.
When the user goes to the edit page to change the CoreValues on the question I want that the listbox has those corevalues already selected any idea on how I could do that?

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class AdminEditViewModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string SubjecTypeName { get; set; }
    public string CoreValueName { get; set; }
    public SelectList SubjectTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValuesOfCoreValues { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CoreValue> CoreValues { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my GET and POST actions in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
            Question question = AdminRep.GetQuestionById(id);
            AdminEditViewModel model = new AdminEditViewModel();
            List<SubjectType> subjectypes = AdminRep.GetAllSubjectTypesById();
            model.CoreValues = AdminRep.GetAllCorevaluesById();
            model.QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
            model.SubjectTypes = new SelectList(subjectypes, "Id", "Name",question.SubjectType.First().Id);


            return View(model);
}

        //
        // POST: /Admin/Edit/5

[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult EditConfirmed(int id, AdminEditViewModel model)
{

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Question question = AdminRep.GetQuestionById(id);
                question.QuestionText = model.QuestionText;
                question.SubjectType.Clear();
                question.CoreValue.Clear();
                foreach (var item in model.SelectedValuesOfCoreValues)
                {
                    var CoreValueID = int.Parse(item);
                    var GetAllCoreValuesID = AdminRep.GetByCoreValueID(CoreValueID);
                    question.CoreValue.Add(GetAllCoreValuesID);

                }
                var SubjectTypeID = int.Parse(model.SubjecTypeName);
                var getallS = AdminRep.GetBySubjectTypeID(SubjectTypeID);
                question.SubjectType.Add(getallS);
                AdminRep.save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }    
             return View(model);
}
```

and my View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValuesOfCoreValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.CoreValues, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "selectstyle" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CoreValueName)
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194143/challenges-with-selecting-values-in-listboxfor

Answer (score 0):

you can make your action method accept a FormCollection as the parameter. You can then write your own logic to pull whatever data you need from that object. Basically the FormCollection will contain all fields inside the form that is posted as a key-value pair.

The signature would look like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form) {   // logic here to  }
```