# Set a Default selected option in Listboxfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ListBoxfor to populate a list of names.   It is fully working. I just want that ListboxFor  preselects the top value by default when a user opens the form.

Here is my code

```
%= Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Names, Model.Names, new { Class = "NamesControl"})%>
```

How can I make the first option highlighted selected by default?

In comments I was pointed to another answer.    but it changes the controller to select the items by default. Is there a way I can only change in view?

Here is my Model

```
public List<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; } 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In my view I had following code

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Name, Model.Names, new { Class = "NamesControl" })%>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194143/challenges-with-selecting-values-in-listboxfor

Comment: Thank you. But I was wondering if there is a way I do not have to change the controller and just change the view?   

Are you pointing to somewhat this 
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Names, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(new[] {      new SelectListItem() { Value = "1" }}))

Comment: @user3540365   I just want  to select the first item as default. If the user didnt select anything then the first option  is passed to the url.

The link you gave me posts about a problem with selecting values in the first place.  I am able to do that , and also I am able to allow user to select values and pass it to form.    The only thing is to select first option by default and show in blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
@Html.ListBox(m => m.Names, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(new[] { new SelectListItem() { Value = "1",Text="Abc",Selected=true }}))
```

Edit 2:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Names, new SelectList(new listName_With_Id()(), "Id", "Name", "3"), new { Class = "NamesControl"})
```

`Name` with `Id =3` will be `selected by default` here.

Comment: I am not usign ListBox but listBoxfor?
any way using ListBoxFor?

I just want to select the first item as default. If the user didnt select anything then the first option is passed to the url.

Comment: just to explain in simple words. 

My project is fully working. I can select an option from ListBoxfor and search using that option.      But  I want  the top option (which has Value 1) to be selected by default and I can still select the others if I want .

Comment: @user2961712, See now.
hope this helps you.

Comment: what is the listName_with_Id?

In my model I have these objects 
public List<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

and In my view I had following code 
 <%= Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Name, Model.Names, new { Class = "NamesControl" })%>

Comment: I have also added these details in the question